# "minikube start" failed on mac

Tags: macos, minikube

When I attempt to run minikube on locally, I got this error:

```
minikube start
Starting local Kubernetes v1.8.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Getting VM IP address...
Moving files into cluster...
E1229 09:52:55.432296    8935 start.go:223] Error updating cluster:  Error updating localkube from uri: Error creating localkube asset from url: Error opening file asset: /Users/user007/.minikube/cache/localkube/localkube-v1.8.0: open /Users/user007/.minikube/cache/localkube/localkube-v1.8.0: no such file or directory
```

How can I fix this problem? I tried many ways, but no one worked.

My system is macOS Sierra.

Comment: this tutorial is very recent about the install and start of minikube on mac osx: https://lvthillo.com/get-started-with-your-local-kubernetes/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a recurring issue. Check out the github issues here: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2468

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue and followed Chris Darby link (https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2468).

I managed to fix it with the following workaround (considering the new version 1.9.0):

- Download [localkube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/download/v0.25.0/localkube)
- Rename it to localkube-v1.9.0
- Copy the file
  in ~/.minikube/cache/localkube/localkube-v1.9.0